# Is there a way to exploit local redundancy in a function to speed up Monte Carlo integration?

Tags: integration, operator-theory, power-series, exponential-function

In every Monte Carlo method I've ever seen, $f$ must be recomputed from scratch for each point that is (somehow randomly) selected to contribute to the overall integral.

However, most functions have output values that are close to each other for close input values (or maybe only smooth differentiable functions?  I'm not a mathematician).  With a large enough number of samples points for an integral, it seems as though you could exploit this fact to reduce the overall computation time.

I'm not quite sure how this would be done... I know that $e^{aD}$ corresponds to the shift operator where $D$ is the differential operator such that $e^{a \frac{d}{dx}}f(x) = f(x+a)$, and if you expand $e^{aD}$ in its power series (it's defined this way, right?) then it basically relies on the infinite number of derivatives at $f(x)$.  Which means that there is enough information contained at $f(x)$ (assuming $f$ is infinitely, or at least highly,  differentiable) that is sufficient to calculate $f$ at a different location.

In this sense, assuming derivatives are easy to calculate, perhaps the Monte Carlo integration could utilize this fact somehow?

So what I want to know is 1) does my idea have any promise and 2) is there a different way (that has already been discovered) to exploit redundancy in a function to speed up Monte Carlo integration?

Comment: Why Monte Carlo integration? While there exist so many other (more efficient?) numerical methods. Are your functions one-dimensional BTW?

Comment: No, they are very high dimensional.

Comment: Ah, that explains! I have had disappointing results with Monte Carlo myself, quite a long time ago. And my integrals were only two-dimensional. But I'm not trying to discourage anybody :-(

Comment: Oh, I bet the curse of dimension strikes here ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Surprisingly, the error is always $O(1/\sqrt{N})$ where $N$ is the number of points sampled, regardless of dimension.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Sure, and any "improvement" I've tried on this involves a "curse" of $O(2^N)$ additional operations.

Comment: Your use of the word "redundancy" is confusing. Do you mean "slowly varying" or "essentially constant" (perhaps with some upper bound of variation, $\epsilon$)? It sounds like you mean not redundancy, but that some functions vary slowly, practically speaking (not "slowly varying" in a theoretical sense).